# Parse Error on Input '<-' inside a do block?

Tags: haskell, parsec, parse-error

I'm trying to do some parsing in Haskell using Parsec. I've got a number of parsers in my code, but am getting an error on one of them:

```
expression2 =
    do (operator lexer "|"
        a <- alternate
        as <- expression2
        return $ a:as
  ) <|> return []
```

The error is `parse error on input '<-`, on the `a <- alternate` line.

Can anyone explain why I'm getting this error, and how to fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you put the parens in the wrong place?

```
expression2 =
   (do  operator lexer "|"
        a <- alternate
        as <- expression2
        return $ a:as) <|> return []
```

Comment: Yes I did; thank you. The one at the end was ok, but I needed to put the first one before the `do`.